# log4j log file is not refreshing automatically

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using notepad++ to preview log files from running java application with log4j logging mechanism. NP++ has a feature where file is automatically reloaded when focus is switched to it, which I find very convenient. Problem here is that new lines are not displayed automatically, even though they are added to file. I can see that if I reload file manually or open it from another text editor. It looks like file is being locked because I cannot delete it until app is closed. I tried executing the same app in Linux but there file is not locked. I can live with manually refreshing file, but I'm concerned if I did something wrong here. Setting locking to false doesn't seem to help here.

I'm using log4j v2.9.1 and running app from wincmd with:

```
java -jar log.jar
```

This is log4jconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration name="ConfigName">
    <Appenders>
        <File locking="false" immediateFlush="true" bufferedIO="false" name="LogFile" fileName="C:\path\to\test.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Java code:

```
public class Main {
    static {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "C:\\path\\to\\log4jconfig.xml");
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Testing...");

        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Does anyone see a problem here?